# How do I call a JS Function in another file?

Tags: javascript, function, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I call a function which is stored in an other function?

I created two js files (File A and File B). In file A I created a function called "getFiles" and I would like to call this function in File B.

File A:

```
export function getFiles(input){
    ...
}
```

File B:

```
import {getFiles} = from './A.js';

getFiles('');
```

But I'm getting the error message "Module '"./A.js"' has no exported member 'getFiles'."

Does anyone know how I can call the function in File B?

Comment: Provide code of what you have tried?

Comment: which web pages have you read about `export` in JavaScript?

Comment: why do you post images of code, do you expect us to type it all in, and this is not searchable by SO or Google

Comment: why don't you load/import the file the same as you do for `vscode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the js File A I had to create a class to be able to export the function.
The class had to be exported with "module.exports"

```
module.exports = class A {
    getFiles(input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And now in File B I had to add a require line to this class:

```
const A = require('./A.js');
```

And now I can call my function "getFiles" from File A:

```
// vscode extension function
function activate(context) {
    const a = new A();
    a.getFiles('');
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Answer (score 2):

You can use [import/export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

For example:

file A.js:

```
export function func1(){

...

}
```

file B.js:

```
import { func1 } from './A.js';
... 
func1();
```

Comment: When I do this I get a error if I start it.
"Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: @DominicSaladin 1: Should be A.ts and B.ts  2:Html should not  link  A.ts and B.ts by <script> element , you can try again -.-